# Is there a way to use React states in firestore collection() and doc()?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm still slightly new to React and Firestore. I was wondering if there is a way for me to target a specific collection in Firestore based on the user's input.

I have tried doing this

```
constructor() {
   super();
   this.state = {
      country: "",
      city: "",
      population: "",
   }
}

addData = () => {
   var itemRef = db.collection(this.state.country).doc(this.state.city);

   itemRef.set({
      country: this.state.country,
      city: this.state.city,
      population: this.state.population
   });
}
```

changing the itemRef to `db.collection("United States").doc("Los Angeles")` does work.
I was hoping that I could store the data into the right collections based on a list of options given to the user when filling up the form.

Would you say this is possible or does firestore not have such function available?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Firestore.  Your variable just doesn't contain the value you expect.  All you're showing right now is that `this.state` contains a bunch of empty string properties.  Use a debugger to figure out what the values actually are before you execute the query.

Comment: Oh that makes sense! Thanks for the advice.